# post comment to a music forum

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I am trying to build a tiny music forum that require user to register and log in to comment on the song they like, their infomation will be stored in mysql database. I'm using MVC model to control everything: Register, Signout, Login. But now i don't know how to let user post comment and show all their comment below the song's page (their comment also be stored in database). Here is my code i have tried so far:

controller.java:

```
String action = request.getParameter("submit");

      if (action.equals("Register")){
            String Uname = request.getParameter("uname");
            String Pword = request.getParameter("pass");
            String Email = request.getParameter("mail");

            boolean check = false;
            try {
                signin signin = new signin();
                check = signin.check(Uname);
                if (check)
                    request.setAttribute("error","This user has already been registered");
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception");
            }
            if (check){
                RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("signin.jsp");
                dispatch.forward(request, response);
            }
            else{
                try{
                    signin signin = new signin();
                    signin.register(Uname, Email, Pword);
                    response.sendRedirect("registersuccess.jsp");
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Exception");
                }
            }
      }
      if (action.equals("Login")){
            HttpSession session=request.getSession();
            String username=request.getParameter("u1");   
            String password=request.getParameter("u2");
            boolean check = false;
            try {
                signin a = new signin ();
                check = a.checkuser(username, password);
            }
            catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Exception");}
           if(check){
                session.setAttribute("username",username);
                response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
            }
            else{
                request.setAttribute("error","ERROR! Wrong Username or Password. Try again!");
                RequestDispatcher dispatch=request.getRequestDispatcher("signinfail.jsp");
                dispatch.forward(request, response);             
            }
        }
      if (action.equals("Logout")){
            HttpSession session=request.getSession();
            session.invalidate();
            response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
        }
```

bean.java:

```
 public void register(String uname, String pass, String email) 
         throws SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {

    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "webauth";
    String userName = "root";
    String passWord = "";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, passWord);
    PreparedStatement statement;
    statement = conn.prepareStatement("insert into data(username, email, password)" + " values (?,?,?)");
    statement.setString(1, uname);
    statement.setString(2, pass);
    statement.setString(3, email);
    statement.executeUpdate();
    statement.clearParameters();
    statement.close();
    conn.close();
}

public boolean check(String username)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, SQLException {

    boolean b = false;
    Connection connection = null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webauth", "root", "");
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT username FROM data");
    while (rs.next()) {
        if (rs.getString("username").equals(username)) {
            b = true;
            break;
        } else {
            b = false;
        }
    }
    rs.close();
    return b;
}

public boolean checkuser(String username, String password)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, SQLException {

    boolean b = false;
    Connection connection = null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webauth", "root", "");
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT username,password FROM data");
    while (rs.next()) {
        if (rs.getString("username").equals(username) && rs.getString("password").equals(password)) {
            b = true;
            break;
        } else {
            b = false;
        }
    }
    rs.close();
    return b;
}
```

Comment: The question seems very vague... "MVC" is very general term. What exactly is the problem? What have you done to solve the problem? What frameworks are you using? Does the code in question actually have anything to do with adding a comment?

Comment: actually i have no idea how post and show all comment that users posted below the song. All I can do is just store it in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the song has a unique id, create an sql query that only shows comments for that song, then create a partial view and use that to display comments for that song.

example

select * from table where song id = your variable

you can then create a partial view that display all comments for that song

hope it points you in the right direction